# If a specific value is inputed into an input box, display a message using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm can't figure out a way of displaying a message if a specific word is inputed into an input box. I'm basically trying to get javascript to display a message if a date, such as '01/07/2013', is inputed into the input box.

Here is my html 
   `<p>Arrival Date</p> <input type="text" id="datepicker" id="food" name="arrival_date"  >`

I'm using a query data picker to select the date.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `.val()` to get the value of the input and compare it with a string

```
var str = $('#datapicker').val(),   // jQuery

   // str = document.getDocumentByI('datapicker').value ( vanilla js)

    strToCompare = '01/07/2013';

if( str === strToCompare) {

    // do something
}
```

And encase this in either `change` or any keyup event to invoke it..

```
$('#datepicker').change(function() {

     // code goes here
});
```

**Update**

Try the code below.

```
$(function () {
    var $datepicker = $('#datepicker');
    $datepicker.datepicker();
    $datepicker.on('change', function () {
        var str = $datepicker.val(),
            strToCompare = '07/19/2013';

        if (str === strToCompare) {

            console.log('Strings match')
        }
        else {
             console.log('boom !!')   
        }
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/TMp3m/)**

Comment: Sorry man, it didn't work. I added document.write within the (do something) section and it didn't display any text.

Comment: can you show the code that you have written.. Avoid using `document.write` .. Try using console.log

Comment: allardadam.me.uk/javascript -- I just uploaded

Comment: You have not specified the change evnet handler

Comment: I just changed the javascript method

Comment: It works perfectly fine.. Just that the value are different `$datepicker.val()` is just in a different format `19/07/2013` .. You can always debug the code  using the developer tools in console. Open the sources tab and put a break point inside the change event and trigger the event .. Then step thru the code

Answer (score 1):

You can insert code in attribute `onchange`

```
onchange="if(this.value == 'someValue') alert('...');"
```

---

Or create new function

```
function change(element){
    if(element.value == 'someValue'){
        alert('...');
    }
}
```

And add attribute

```
onchange="change(this);"
```

Or add event

```
var el = document.getElementById('input-id');
el.onchange = function(){
    change(el); // if 'el' doesn't work, use 'this' instead
}
```

I'm not sure if it works, but it should :)

Answer (score 0):

Your input has 2 ids. You need to remove `id="food"`. Then the following should work with IE >= 9:

```
document.getElementById('datepicker').addEventListener(
  'input',
  function(event) {
    if (event.target.value.match(/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/))
      console.log("Hello");
  }, false);
```